# Which buffs affect the -blade tomes?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I've got a Flier Emblem team set up with Spring Camilla at the head, wielding the mighty Gronnblade+, which adds all buffs as raw damage when calculating her attack power. As in all Flier Emblem teams, I've also got a Flier (Caeda) with Fortify Fliers and a Flier (Hinoka) with Hone Fliers. Lastly, I've got either Cordelia or Cherche with Goad Fliers, but since the Arena currently has Summer Robin as a bonus unit, I've replaced the last position in my roster with her, who has Hone Spd 3.

However, when doing Arena challenges, I noticed something. Not all of the buffs were being added to Spring Camilla's damage. This didn't usually matter, as she tends to reach 70-85 damage on a single hit, but Summer Robin's Hone Spd 3 didn't seem to add anything to Spring Camilla's attack. The buffs from Fortify/Hone Fliers definitely added onto her attack, though.

Which buffs affect the -blade (Gronnblade, Blarblade, Rauorblade) tomes? I assume the buff from skills like Fury or Life & Death that passively affect stats do not affect the damage, while the Hone/Fortify/Ward skills that add buffs at the beginning of each turn do. What about the Hone skills that only add buffs for adjacent or nearby allies during combat?

Comment: Not an answer because I'm not sure if it's true in this case, but I've noticed you can't stack the same bonuses in many cases. So if you're already getting +6 speed from Hone Fliers you won't get any other speed buffs. I know you can't Rally units that have been buffed by a Hone skill or similar.

Comment: @adaliabooks ah, is that true? Is the max amount for a stat to get buffed +6 then? I was experimenting and noticed a Hone skill did just affect my damage...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but that's what I've noticed. I think even a +4 buff will stop other +4 buffs, but if you've only buffed +1 or +2 you can still buff further with Rally. I haven't bothered to really experiment and find the limits though, it's just my experience.

Comment: @adaliabooks that must be it then. It seems that it wasn't that certain buffs weren't affecting me, it's that only the highest buffs count (or something)

Comment: From what i experienced with Tharja (red blade tome), is that different buffs stack, but only the highest for that stat. That means that you can have both a +4 Attack buff and a +4 Speed Buff that counts extra for the blade tome. But a +4 Speed and +6 Speed buff will only result in +6 being counted.
Also, only out of combat buffs work, so not the Spur skills for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I determined the source of my confusion. While the Spur skills affect your stats in combat, they will **not** buff the damage of the "-blade" tomes.

To illustrate this, I compared the battle outcome of my fully buffed Spring Camilla (+6 all stats) against the same enemy, both next to and not next to my Summer Robin with Spur Spd 3.

[image: spring Camilla with all buffs]

Now, while not next to Summer Robin, Spring Camilla does 38 damage.

[image: without Spur spd]

However, when adjacent to Summer Robin, she still does 38 damage, but now she doubles Marth. This indicates that the additional SPD from Summer Robin's Spur SPD, however, it is not added as raw damage like the +6 on her stats.

[image: with Spur spd]

As for which buffs affect these tomes, the buffs that show up in blue on a unit's stats (and are explicitly listed as buffs) are added as raw damage. Passive buffs from skills like Life or Death or Fury are not counted, neither are the buffs from Spur/Goad skills, though they *are* taken into account.

This means that Goad Fliers (+4 Atk/Spd to friendly fliers within 2 spaces during combat) will add 4 damage (due to the attack stat being boosted), rather than the 12 it would if the buffs were counted as raw damage (+4 for both ATK and SPD, then the additional 4 from the attack stat itself being boosted)